# How do I generate 4 random variables and only printing if it doesn't contain the int 0

Tags: c

this is my code, I want to make a function that when it is called will generate a number between 1111 to 9999, I don't know how to continue or if I've written this right. Could someone please help me figure this function out. It suppose to be simple.

I had to edit the question in order to clarify some things. This function is needed to get 4 random digits that is understandable from the code. And the other part is that i have to make another function which is a **bool**. The bool needs to first of get the numbers from the function **get_random_4digits** and check if there contains a 0 in the number. If that is the case then the other function, lets call it **unique_4digit**, should disregard of that number that contained a 0 in it and check for a new one to use. I need not help with the function **get_random_4digits**because it is correct. I need helt constructing a **bool** that takes **get_random_4digits** as an argument to check if it contains a 0. My brain can't comprehend how I first do the **get_random_4digit** then pass the answer to **unique_4digits** in order to check if the random 4 digits contains a 0 and only make it print the results that doesn't contain a 0.

So I need help with understanding how to check the random 4 digits for the integer 0 and not let it print if it has a 0, and only let the 4 random numbers print when it does not contain a 0.

the code is not suppose to get more complicated than this.

```
int get_random_4digit(){
    int lower = 1000, upper = 9999,answer;
    answer = (rand()%(upper-lower)1)+lower;
    return answer;
}

bool unique_4digits(answer){
    if(answer == 0)
        return true;

    if(answer < 0)
        answer = -answer;

    while(answer > 0) {
        if(answer % 10 == 0)
            return true;
        answer /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

```
    printf("Random answer %d\n", get_random_4digit());
    printf("Random answer %d\n", get_random_4digit());
    printf("Random answer %d\n", get_random_4digit());
```

Comment: Seems like it might be appropriate to use `sprintf` to get a string representation and then walk the string looking for '0'.

Comment: is there any easier way, not using something like sprintf? With an easier way i'm talking about modifying the code i've written to see if it contains a 0.

Comment: There seems to be a typo here: `answer = (rand()%(upper-lower)1)+lower;`. `)1` should be `+1`.

Comment: it is +1 I don't know why the edit showed it like that

Comment: just generate 4 digits between 1 and 9 and then concatenate them

Comment: If `unique_4digits` is supposed to check at least 4 digits, it should check for values between -999 and 999 inclusive since they only have 3 digits or less.

Comment: Why, why, WHY...?! Why do you need to generate 4-digit codes again and again until you find one without zero? Wouldn't it be easier, faster and cheaper to generate such zero-free code at once, ready to use???

Comment: "I need not help with the function get_random_4digitsbecause it is correct." ---> Not quite.  First post true compile-able code.

Comment: Your description of what you want `unique_4digits` to do is a bit confusing. It sounds like you want it to repeatedly call `get_random_4digit` until it gets a "good" number and then print it. But then what would be the purpose of the `bool` return value?

Comment: It is faster and cheaper using for loop but the code should only contain if and while statements and no for loops.

Comment: Ian I am new to coding, like 1 month new, man i'm just trying to understand how to do this. I might explain things in a wrong way. But that is only because i'm new to this and half of the thing I do i might not be able to explain or understand so well.

Comment: @KevinAbdul "only contain if and while statements and no for loops." is unclear.  A `while` statement is a loop.

Comment: then I meant no for loops, only while and ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of testing each generated code for a disqualifying zero just generate a code without zero in it:

```
int generate_zero_free_code()
{
    int n;
    int result = 0;

    for (n = 0; n < 4; n ++)
        result = 10 * result + rand() % 9;   // add a digit 0..8

    result += 1111;  // shift each digit from range 0..8 to 1..9
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what if I can't use a for loop, how do I translate that to ifs and whiles?

Comment: The most expensive function here is `rand()` and called 4 times.  Only once is needed.

Comment: Yes okay, but my question was what if I can't use for loops, and need to only use if and while. How do I convert his code to something using ifs and whiles together or separate.

Comment: **1.** It's absurd to require a beginner to program without loops. Unless you're not a beginner and you need to learn loop unrolling...? **2.** I can't see in your question any note about avoiding loops. **3.** You actually DO use loops – your `unique_4digits` function uses a `while()` loop.

Comment: @chux Yes – but at this level of programming skills it's way more important to learn writing a legible code than a fast one.

Comment: `result = 10 * result + (rand() % 9 + 1);` is more legible than a post `result += 1111;`

Comment: @ciapan I can use loops but just not for loops, loops like do while or while loops i can use but just not for loops. I want to understand how to write your code using only while and ifs(if ifs are even needed). But the important part is that I don't use for loops. That is just the instructions.

Comment: This code was helpful but I want to understand how to write it using while.

Comment: @ciapan please if you have the time edit it using while loops. I honestly think that your answer was the most legit one because of the simplicity.

Comment: @KevinAbdul - _" please if you have the time edit it using while loops."_...   Can you not just take something and modify it yourself?

Comment: @ryyker what is it you don't understand. I just started coding. Do you think it's just that simple to translate for loops? I have tried to do it for the last 50 minutes. I wouldn't be asking if I could do it.

Comment: @KevinAbdul - `for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++){...}` is equivalent to `int i=0; while(i<10){...;i++;)`  where `...` is just what ever code is being run in the construct.

Comment: @KevinAbdul then just write the line 4 times

Answer (score 1):

You can run the number, dividing it by 10 and checking the rest of it by 10:

```
int a = n // save the original value
while(a%10 != 0){
    a = a / 10;
}
```

And then check the result:

```
if (a%10 != 0) printf("%d\n", n);
```

Edit: making it a stand alone function:

```
bool unique_4digits(int n)
{
    while(n%10 != 0){
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return n != 0;
}
```

Usage: `if (unique_4digits(n)) printf("%d\n", n);`

Comment: Or the complete mess in 2 lines: `while ((a /= 10)%10 > 0);` `if (!a%10) printf("n: %d\n", n);`

Comment: but how do I apply this to my functions? The whole point was to use the functions, and not doing this in the main.

Comment: typo...:  `boll`

Answer (score 0):

To test if the number doesn't contain any zero you can use a function that returns zero if it fails and the number if it passes the test :

```
bool FourDigitsWithoutZero() {
    int n = get_random_4digit();
    if (n % 1000 < 100 || n % 100 < 10 || n % 10 == 0) return 0;
    else return n;
}
```

Comment: but how do I apply this to my functions? The whole point was to use the functions, and not doing this in the main.

Comment: What you want to do with your functions is unclear to me, but if you know how to select numbers with not any zero you can use such test in your own codes (naturally not in main, it's just for the example).

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need not help with the function get_random_4digits because it is correct."*

Actually the following does not compile,

```
int get_random_4digit(){
    int lower = 1000, upper = 9999,answer;
    answer = (rand()%(upper-lower)1)+lower;
    return answer;
}
```

[image]

The following includes modifications that do compile, but still does not match your stated objectives::

```
int get_random_4digit(){
    srand(clock());
    int lower = 1000, upper = 9999,answer;
    int range = upper-lower;
    answer = lower + rand()%range;
    return answer;
}
```

> *" I want to make a function that when it is called will generate a number between 1111 to 9999,"*

This will do it using a helper function to test for zero:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf( "Random answer %d\n", random_range(1111, 9999));        
    printf( "Random answer %d\n", random_range(1111, 9999));
    printf( "Random answer %d\n", random_range(1111, 9999));
    printf( "Random answer %d\n", random_range(1111, 9999));

    return 0;
}
```

Function that does work follows:

```
int random_range(int min, int max)
{
   bool zero = true;
   char buf[10] = {0};
   int res = 0;
   srand(clock());
   while(zero)
   { 
       res = min + rand() % (max+1 - min);
       sprintf(buf, "%d", res);
       zero = if_zero(buf);       
    }
    return res;
 }

bool if_zero(const char *num)
{
     while(*num)
     {
          if(*num == '0') return true;
          num++;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is way to complicated for me. I'm thankful for the time you took to write this! Hopefully i'll understand this one day. But i've never worked with "buf".

Comment: @KevinAbdul - Too complicated?  `buf` is to contain a string representation of a multi-digit number, from which can be searched for a `0` character.  It is just an alternative method to what is already shown.